# Is Liferay 7.0 EE compatible with Weblogic 10.3.6?

Tags: deployment, liferay, weblogic

I am trying to deploy Liferay 7 locally on my Weblogic server, but receiving Forbidden 403 error when accessing URL at http://localhost:7004/liferay_7

```
Error 403--Forbidden
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:

10.4.4 403 Forbidden
The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable.
```

I have tried Liferay 6.1 CE on my weblogic server by following the guide below, and everything worked fine.
https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-1/installing-liferay-on-oracle-weblogic-10-3?notice=1

But I could only find a guide on Liferay 7 with weblogic 12c in which the instructions are very different. I suspect it is a configuration issue, but I'm at the end of my wits to figure out what is exactly wrong.

I appreciate all your suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Compatibility Matrix](https://web.liferay.com/en/services/support/compatibility-matrix), Liferay DXP (there is no 7 EE) is limited to Weblogic 12 indeed. This is a good assumption for Liferay 7 CE as well.

Comment: Thanks for the link.